# Why isn't this C funtion calculating sqrt working for decimals?

Tags: c++, sqrt

```
#include <iostream>

float calculating_root(float N, float root_N, float increment)
{
    int safety=1;
    while(safety==1)
    {
        if (N == (root_N*root_N))
        {
            safety=0;
            return root_N;  
        }
        else if(N<((root_N+increment)*(root_N+increment)))
        {
            safety=0;
            return calculating_root(N,root_N, increment*0.1);
        }
        root_N=root_N+increment;
    }
}

int main()
{
    float N, root_N=0.0, increment=1000.0;

    scanf("%f",&N);

    float x = calculating_root(N, root_N, increment);

    printf("\n%g\n",x);

    return 0;
}
```

I've been thinking about it for such a long time. I guess I don't have other ideas, everything seems perfect? Does anyone sees a mistake?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What happens when you try to run the code? How is that different from what is supposed to happen? What happened when you [tried to solve the problem yourself](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) (which is [expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users))? Please also read [ask].

Comment: You can get rid of `safety`: `while (safety==1)` -> `while (true)`

Comment: Floating comparisons such as `N == (root_N * root_N)` is really fragile.

Comment: Can't reproduce (I tried different input numbers and always got a good square root). But the `==` operator on `float` variables can often be the source of failure.

Comment: That's what I was thinking about. But how can I do something about ==? And I noticed that also the < operator isn't really working. When comparing the same numbers it returns true...

Comment: @AdrianMole: I have infinite loop for `N == 6.f` or `N == 0.01f`.

Comment: Related to [is-floating-point-math-broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

Comment: why do you say it would be C? `<iostream>` is not C, though you arent using it but instead miss other includes for the C functions you are using. Please only tag the language you are actually using to compile the code. When you compile it as C++ then it is C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `==` for comparing floating point numbers that you calculated is not advised. Especially in this case `N` might actually be a number that is not representable by any float `a` such that `a*a == N`.

so instead of

```
N == (root_N*root_N)
```

try to use something like

```
fabs(N-(root_N*root_N)) < epsilon
```

Where epsilon is your acceptable rounding error. You could choose something like `const float epsilon = 0.000001f`. I think in this case you might need something above the machine epsilon, because you're potentially accumulating the error.

You could also improve precision somewhat by using `double` instead of `float`. That will however not replace the need for the epsilon, only allow you to choose a lower epsilon.

Comment: Note also, that for big number, the `increment` will be to small compared to `N_root`. It that case, `N_root + increment` will be equal to`N_root` and the loop will be infinite...

Comment: Thank you very much! I used double and this epsilon thing and it's working PERFECTLY ;) Also I made an additional if statement at the very beginning, so if the increment is too small, the function returns root_N